# How do I install npm packages on Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a simple function that:

- fetches a JSON file from a public URL
- does a little number crunching and spits out an answer.

I figured that Google Cloud Functions would be the perfect fit since I can code in JS and don`t have to worry about server deployment, etc.

I've never really used `nodejs`/`npm` so maybe this is the issue, but I tried reading online and they just mention

```
npm install package-name
```

I'm not sure where I can do this on the Google Cloud Functions page.

I'm currently using the inline editor and I have the following:

```
var fetch = require('node-fetch');

exports.test2 = (req, res) => {
  fetch("myURLgoes here").then(function(response){
        res.status(200).send('Success:'+response);
    });
```

I get the following error:

> Error: function crashed.Details:
>   fetch is not defined

Comment: you should use `npm install package-name --save` so can be use with google cloud.

Comment: @Dkouk where do I type that though? I'm just using the browser to edit the code inline.

Comment: you should use `CLI`, how do editing and insall JS code, and node command ?

Comment: @Dkouk I use the inline editor on their website. https://screenshots.firefox.com/l7kJabMgKdUz2cKn/console.cloud.google.com

Comment: @Dkouk okay I see there is a cloud shell on the interface however it doesn't show the code that contains my google cloud functions. I can do the npm install and see the npm_modules directory however I don't see my Google Cloud Functions index.js & package.js code.

Comment: why not working on you're local machine, and can deploy to google cloud ?

Answer (score 9):

From Google Cloud Platform console, go to your cloud functions.

You should have two files when creating or editing a functions:
- index.js: where you define your functions
- package.json: where you define your dependency.

Your package.json at the start is something like this:

```
{
  "name": "sample-http",
  "version": "0.0.1"
}
```

Add in your package.json all your module that you'd like to install with the command npm install as below:

```
{
  "name": "sample-http",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```

you can find the last version of the package on www.npmjs.com

Answer (score -1):

You can run the npm command from the Google Cloud Shell (which you can access from the Google Cloud Console).