# Why does my Cloud Function deployment fail with an INVALID_ARGUMENT error?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless

I am working on a Google Cloud Functions Project and I want to use the AWS-SDK so I edit the  package.json and it looks like this:

```
{"name": "sample-http",
    "version": "0.0.1"
      "dependencies": {
        "aws-sdk": "2.574.0"
    }
  }
```

The deployment crashes with the following message in the logs: INVALID_ARGUMENT

I am working in the Browser environment.
Can somebody help or does it have something to do with the fact that I don't use the paid plan until now?

I already saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428733/how-do-i-install-npm-packages-on-google-cloud-functions/58937219#58937219) but the answer is not working for me as you can see.

Comment: Typically you don't manually edit package.json to add dependencies to node projects.  It's easier to run `npm install ...` to add them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid, it is missing a comma after the `version` item:

```
{
  "name": "sample-http",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
      "aws-sdk": "2.574.0"
  }
}
```

Using `npm install` to create a `package.json` should allow you to avoid issues like this.  Additionally, there's a good number of publicly usable JSON validators on the web to test for issues like this.

Comment: thanks a lot, should have validated the JSON first!

Answer (score 0):

by some reason when I install packages for cloud functions, package Json is not updated