# Firebase cloud functions: ffmpeg version

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have firebase function using the node12 runtime on which I use ffmpeg. The installed ffmpeg version is 3.4.8, which has a few quirks compared to the 4.* version.

Does anybody know, if the higher node versions come with an updated ffmpeg binary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ffmpeg-static you chose the binary you need.
And it does not require building. It will download the binary when installing dependencies.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ffmpeg-fb",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/ffmpeg-static": "^3.0.1",
    "ffmpeg-static": "^4.4.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.18.1"
  }
}
```

and then the index.ts

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as  pathToFFMPEG from 'ffmpeg-static'
import * as child_process from 'child_process';

export const ffmpegTest = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    functions.logger.info("FFMPEG Path " + pathToFFMPEG, {structuredData: true});

    await new Promise((resolve) => {
        const cmd = child_process.spawn(pathToFFMPEG, ['-version'], { shell: true });
        cmd.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
            functions.logger.info(`stdout: ${data}`);
            
        });
        cmd.on('error', (error) => {
            functions.logger.info(`error: ${error}`);
        });

        cmd.on('close', (code) => {
            resolve(undefined);
        });
    });
    response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, you can try to add the package version of ffmpeg like the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/handle-dependencies) says. You just need to [specify which version](https://nodejs.dev/learn/install-an-older-version-of-an-npm-package) to install using the normal  `npm install <package>@<version>` syntax, or also specify it in the `package.json` file as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428733/how-do-i-install-npm-packages-on-google-cloud-functions):

You can also check if this procedure works with the command  `ffmpeg --version`

```json
{
  "name": "sample-http",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "ffmpeg": "0.0.4"
  }
}
```

*I used the version included in the [git](https://github.com/damianociarla/node-ffmpeg/blob/master/package.json) repository.

**feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this will work. As the docs for node-ffmpeg say: `To use this library requires that ffmpeg is already installed (including all necessary encoding libraries like libmp3lame or libx264)`

Comment: You can get to know the [Node.js Runtime Environment](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/nodejs-runtime) and [Google Cloud Functions Execution environment](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec), then try the solution offered above, the documentation of GCF and Firebase Functions (first link of the answer) follow the mentioned procedure. Using `npm` and specifying the dependency in the `package.json` file. The libraries for `ffmpeg` must be there as there is already a version of it installed. If that does not work, I will continue helping.